# Qt5 - Blocking QWidget update() function call from its children

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a root widget to contain all different widgets as children. Some are `QOpenGLWidgets` some are regular `QWidget`.

Every time I want to update a single widget, I would call `update()` in child's widget. However I found that Qt actually fires a child's parent `update()` function if child's `update()` was called. Which makes my `QOpenGLWidget` updated many more times than I need (when one `QWidget` child `update()`, it fires parent's `update()`, and a parent's `update()` may fire its children's `update()`). It is kinda annoying because it slows the gl rendering. And sometimes if updates happen too frequently, my `QOpenGLWidget` may flicker because I haven't done updating my frameBuffer yet and it is swapped to the screen.

I know Qt may optimize some `update()` calls if scheduled `update()` are many. But it didn't solve my issue here. I have tried `QWidget::setUpdatesEnabled()` to my root widget but it actually blocks all `update()` for its children except for itself (though I `setUpdatesEnabled(true)` to its children).

It would be great to let `QOpenGLWidget` to schedule `update()` itself instead of its parent fires `update()` for it. So my question is, is there any way to block `update()` call to a specific parent/children?

Platform: Qt5.6.2, Ubuntu 16.04, OpenGL3.3

Comment: You could try `setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent)` on the child widget that requires frequent updating to see what effect that has (if any).

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for the suggestion, however it doesn't make quite much difference with that attribute set. I have seen the description about this attribute, it should help a bit I think.